# Guides for learning to plot with pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I've wanted to learn how to make graphs with tikz/pgf for a long time. I'm relatively new to tikz, the only source I've used so far is its massive manual. I know there is no shortage of material on tikz/pgf, there's so much I'm getting a bit overwhelmed. I thought it would be more helpful to ask for some directions before I dive in.

I would like to know what are the community's favorites for learning how to make 2D plots, 3D plots and countour plots with tikz/pgf. I'm looking for tutorials and guides with lots of step-by-step working examples. What are their pros and cons? Please share your thoughts on the references you give. Thanks.

Comment: Just dive in and come back when you have a specific question.  Personally, I prefer to compute numbers in separate programs and pass them to pgfplots as data tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My favourite actually is the Ti*k*Z/PGF manual. It provides some very nice examples for practical use that can serve as a good starting point for your learning. Just follow the steps given there and you will master the basics very quickly! I think there is almost no better (and cheaper) way to learn Ti*k*Z.

Comment: You can also go to https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/plots/ (and around). Recently all the examples have been made editable and compilable on-line...

Comment: [VisualTikZ by Jean Pierre Casteleyn](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf)